Subset of an enum class
In Kotlin, is it possible to define a subset of an enum?
enum class Shape {
    FULL_HEIGHT_WALL, HALF_HEIGHT_WALL, FULL_HEIGHT_CORNER, HALF_HEIGHT_CORNER, SOMETHING_ELSE
}

fun Shape.isFullHeight() = when (this) {
    Shape.FULL_HEIGHT_WALL -> true
    Shape.FULL_HEIGHT_CORNER -> true
    else -> false
}

fun Shape.isHalfHeight() = when (this) {
    Shape.HALF_HEIGHT_WALL -> true
    Shape.HALF_HEIGHT_CORNER -> true
    else -> false
}

fun test(s: Shape) = when {
    s.isFullHeight() -> 1.0f
    s.isHalfHeight() -> 0.5f
    s == Shape.SOMETHING_ELSE -> 0.42f
    // else?!
}

The function isFullHeight is true for a subset of Shape, the function isHalfHeight is true for another. The when statement of the test function should be exhaustive; but since Kotlin does not understand that no enum item remains after the checks, it requires an else case. That's a bit unfortunate, because if I add an else case, the compiler won't complain if I add yet another shape and forget to update the test function.
So, is it possible to rewrite this such that Kotlin understands I'm checking subsets? If not, is this on the roadmap? (I think TypeScript is able to do this.)

You could use EnumSet instances for each of the various subsets and it's contains method instead of the when.

You can make an additional Height enum. Then you can use Height? to represent full, half, or "something else" (null).
enum class Height {
    FULL, HALF
}

enum class Shape {
    FULL_HEIGHT_WALL, HALF_HEIGHT_WALL, FULL_HEIGHT_CORNER, HALF_HEIGHT_CORNER, SOMETHING_ELSE   
}

val Shape.height get() = when (this) {
    Shape.FULL_HEIGHT_WALL, Shape.FULL_HEIGHT_CORNER -> Height.FULL
    Shape.HALF_HEIGHT_WALL, Shape.HALF_HEIGHT_CORNER -> Height.HALF
    else -> null
}

fun test(s: Shape) = when(s.height) {
    Height.FULL -> 1.0f
    Height.HALF -> 0.5f
    null -> 0.42f
}

Another approach is to use a sealed type hierarchy instead. Represent the height of each case by implementing interfaces, and use is in the when to check the type.
sealed interface Shape {
    object FullHeightWall: FullHeight
    object HalfHeightWall: HalfHeight
    object FullHeightCorner: FullHeight
    object HalfHeightCorner: HalfHeight
    object SomethingElse: Shape
}

sealed interface FullHeight: Shape
sealed interface HalfHeight: Shape

fun test(s: Shape) = when(s) {
    is FullHeight -> 1.0f
    is HalfHeight -> 0.5f
    Shape.SomethingElse -> 0.42f
}


The objects should be data objects.

@Leviathan Yeah, ideally. But the feature is kind of new and I was too lazy to explain what the difference is. And the difference doesn't matter that much most of the time anyway.
